# Generating random sentences using specific words in R

Tags: r, dplyr, nlp

I need to generate `n` random sentences using an array of keywords or tokens in R and preferably using dplyr.

Each sentence may have a different number of words.

The array of words is:

```
(Helsinki, Town, big, pollution, a, much, Not, is, nice)
```

and sentences should be in a way that the grammatical order of words in a sentence makes sense and can be something like the following:

```
big Helsinki,
Helsinki is a nice town,
nice Helsinki
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to create more meaningful sentences? in a way that the grammatical order of words in a sentence makes sense?

Comment: You may use `markovifyR` to generate based on markov models or else may need `GPT-2`

Comment: @akrun, thanks! can you please elaborate on this? or provide some examples?

Comment: @Alex you may use `markov_model` to generate model and then use the model in `markovify_text` to get the words as showed [here](https://nandeshwar.info/data-science-2/natural-language-generation-with-r-python/)

Comment: @akrun, thank you! would it be ok if I go through it and get back to you for more guidance if needed?

Comment: Sure, thanks you can check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251135/discussion-between-alex-and-akrun).

Comment: @akrun The issue is that my Corpus is a column of words and not sentences
when I follow the steps with my data, the model gives me the following
```textLinnemanBot: NA
# A tibble: 1 x 2
idRow textLinnemanBot
<int> <lgl>
1 1 NA```
How can I use this model when I have an array of key words as shown in the above example? thank you again

Comment: you may use `library(openai)` and make use of the models in that package.  Here in SO, I guess chatGPT etc are banned so not sure if this is permitted as well

Comment: @akrun, do you happen to know the minimum number of sentences in this algorithm? because when I pulled only ```5``` sentences, it did not generate any texts. when it was ```10```, it generated 1 text, and when ```20```, it only generated ```15```. I assume there must be a ```minimum number of tokens``` to build the model based on.  I wonder if you can share if you are aware?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it

Comment: @akrun, thanks again, do you know how I control the length of sentences? there are four parameters: ```markov_state_size```, ```max_overlap_total```,```max_overlap_rato```, and ```maximum_sentence_length```

Comment: Sorry buddy.  Even talking about openai in SO can get one suspended.